# select all rows containing two values based off of another column

Tags: sql-server-2008

Let's say I have a table that looks like the below. It's basically a table containing history of sales. There's other columns, but I'm only putting the ones that matter here for what I am trying to figure out with how to do SQL query on.

What I want to do is get an output in where I can see all sales in where only papaya and apple were bought.

```
Sales history Table
--------------------------------------
salesnumber | salesdesc
1 | papaya
1 | apple
2 | apple
3 | watermelon
4 | papaya
4 | apple
5 | pomegranate
6 | watermelon
7 | apple
8 | watermelon 
9 | orange
10 | orange

Desired Output
--------------------------------------
salesnumber | salesdesc
1 | papaya
1 | apple
4 | papaya
4 | apple
```

Comment: Please provide your own attempt to achieve result and ask what particular problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`Select * from sales_history_table where salesdesc = 'papaya' or salesdesc = 'apple'`